# CubeMX stm32 FreeRTOS + USB host MSC for USB Flash memory

Tags: memory, usb, stm32, host, drive

Using CubeMX, TrueStudio, an STM32F767ZI, and HAL, I am developing software to access a USB Flash drive using FatFS though the USB host port.
The board has a host and device USB connector attached to the MCU.
Within CubeMX, I configured FreeRTOS, USB Host MSC, and FatFS.
This works, I can see these different states when plugging and unplugging the flash drive:

```
--- Plugging in USB flash drive ---
HOST_USER_CONNECTION
HOST_USER_CONNECTION
HOST_DEV_ATTACHED
phost->device.speed: 1
HOST_ENUMERATION
HOST_SET_CONFIGURATION
HOST_SET_WAKEUP_FEATURE
HOST_CHECK_CLASS
USBH_MSC_InterfaceInit
HOST_CLASS_REQUEST
USBH_MSC_ClassRequest
HOST_CLASS
USBH_MSC_Process
processId: 3, Appli_state 1
USBH_MSC_GetLUNInfo
info.capacity.block_nbr : 623395
info.capacity.block_size: 512
capacity                : 3116 MB
HOST_USER_CLASS_ACTIVE
FATFS_LinkDriver Failed
USBDISKPath:
processId: 2, Appli_state 2
USBH_MSC_GetLUNInfo
info.capacity.block_nbr : 62333951
info.capacity.block_size: 512
capacity                : 31166 MB
--- Unplugging USB flash drive ---
HOST_USER_DISCONNECTION
HOST_DEV_DISCONNECTED
USBH_MSC_InterfaceDeInit
processId: 5, Appli_state 3
USBH_MSC_GetLUNInfo
info.capacity.block_nbr : 62333951
info.capacity.block_size: 512
capacity                : 31166 MB
```

So, after MX_USB_HOST_Init(); was called in freertos.c all the above happened.
FATFS_LinkDriver() is called from MX_FATFS_Init().
But the functions in usbh_diskio.c are not called, so something went wrong there.

The pieces of code I'm looking at are these:

freertos.c, where MX_USB_HOST_Init() is called, after this the MSC is registered.

```
/* StartDefaultTask function */
void StartDefaultTask(void const * argument)
{
  /* init code for FATFS */
  MX_FATFS_Init();

  /* init code for LWIP */
  MX_LWIP_Init();

  /* init code for USB_HOST */
  MX_USB_HOST_Init();

  /* init code for USB_DEVICE */
  MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();

  /* init code for LIBJPEG */
  MX_LIBJPEG_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN StartDefaultTask */

  MSC_LUNTypeDef info;
  uint8_t lun = 0;
  uint16_t val = 0;

  /* Infinite loop */
  for(;;)
  {
      /* USB Host Background task */
//      USBH_Process(&hUsbHostFS);

    val++;
    if (val >= 1000)
    {
        if (processIdOld != processId)
        {
            printf("processId: %d, Appli_state %d\n", processId, Appli_state);
            processIdOld = processId;
              USBH_MSC_GetLUNInfo(&hUSB_Host, lun, &info);
              uint32_t cap = info.capacity.block_nbr / 2000;
              printf("info.capacity.block_nbr : %ld\n", info.capacity.block_nbr);
              printf("info.capacity.block_size: %d\n", info.capacity.block_size);
              printf("capacity                : %d MB\n", cap);
        }
//      printf("1");
//      fflush(stdout);
//      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(PIO10_LED_RS_ERR_GPIO_Port, PIO10_LED_RS_ERR_Pin);
        val = 0;
    }
    osDelay(1);
  }
  /* USER CODE END StartDefaultTask */
}
```

usb_host.c, where USB is initialized, and I can see USBH_UserProcess is called when I plug/unplug the USB flash drive.

```
void MX_USB_HOST_Init(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USB_HOST_Init_PreTreatment */

  /* USER CODE END USB_HOST_Init_PreTreatment */

  /* Init host Library, add supported class and start the library. */
  USBH_Init(&hUsbHostFS, USBH_UserProcess, HOST_FS);

  USBH_RegisterClass(&hUsbHostFS, USBH_AUDIO_CLASS);

  USBH_RegisterClass(&hUsbHostFS, USBH_CDC_CLASS);

  USBH_RegisterClass(&hUsbHostFS, USBH_MSC_CLASS);

  USBH_RegisterClass(&hUsbHostFS, USBH_HID_CLASS);

  USBH_RegisterClass(&hUsbHostFS, USBH_MTP_CLASS);

  USBH_Start(&hUsbHostFS);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USB_HOST_Init_PostTreatment */

  /* USER CODE END USB_HOST_Init_PostTreatment */
}

/*
 * user callback definition
 */
static void USBH_UserProcess  (USBH_HandleTypeDef *phost, uint8_t id)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CALL_BACK_1 */
  switch(id)
  {
  case HOST_USER_SELECT_CONFIGURATION:
      printf("HOST_USER_SELECT_CONFIGURATION\n");
      break;

  case HOST_USER_DISCONNECTION:
      printf("HOST_USER_DISCONNECTION\n");
      Appli_state = APPLICATION_DISCONNECT;
      break;

  case HOST_USER_CLASS_ACTIVE:
      printf("HOST_USER_CLASS_ACTIVE\n");
      Appli_state = APPLICATION_READY;
      break;

  case HOST_USER_CONNECTION:
      printf("HOST_USER_CONNECTION\n");
      Appli_state = APPLICATION_START;
      break;

  default:
      break;
  }
  /* USER CODE END CALL_BACK_1 */
}
```

The above part works fine, sofar.
Except the linking of the usbh driver.
Has anybody used this or know good working examples?

Comment: What have you done so far except the Cube file generation. I do not see eve a single line written by you.

Comment: Next, I need to use the MSC, but I didn't find examples based on CubeMX, yet. In the below code I checked the USBH_UserProcess  is called when pluging in the flash drive, and I added printstatements and drive LEDs to indicate it. I wrote some code to redirect printf to usart2. I wrote more code for a LED driver and RTC, and driving a FT813 display, but all that is not relevant to this part where I like to access the flash drive.

Comment: Can't edit above anymore, 5 minute limit? So continue here I also wrote code for an RTC, ADC, QSPI, SDMMC, and use FatFS to access a 16GB eMMC. That works very well. Now I would like to be able to copy files between the eMMC and a flash drive.